# How to add selector to element HTML?

Tags: javascript

I have a span element:

```
let infoButton = document.createElement("span"); 
infoButton.setAttribute("class", "info-point");
```

How to add selector [bold] to element, to get this:

```
<span [bold] class="info-point"></span>
```

or

```
<span bold class="info-point"></span>
```

Comment: No, I need as I said, it is for Angular directive

Comment: @vy32 these are boolean attributes and are valid in HTML5/4 spec https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861425/angularjs-inserting-directives-dynamically-to-dom-element it is angularjs and I believe you might get idea from it..

Comment: I use Angular 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an attribute with an empty string should give you such results. This is called a boolean attribute (commonly used in frameworks like React, Angular, etc). They are valid as defined in the [W3 Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2).

```js
let infoButton = document.createElement("span"); 
infoButton.setAttribute("class", "info-point");
infoButton.setAttribute("bold", "");
console.log(infoButton);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below directive for making bold text.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[boldText]'
})
export class BoldTextDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<span boldText class="info-point"></span>
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off using the native API to manage element classes.

```
var infoButton = document.createElement("span"); 

infoButton.classList.add("info-point");
```

Comment: This is both correct (you should use the classList API to handle classes), and wrong (the attribute in question is not a class, it's an attribute)